# How to sync the database and the session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, data-integrity

I got a problem, when the user is logged, and I assign the user their id, for example, 126. But when I doing maintain, or delete some banned user, for example, the user id 126 will remove from the database, but the user 126 still have the number 126 in his session. How can I 'delete' his session content when I detect my database have user id is deleted? Thank you.

Comment: ummm, do a check to see if the session is still active within the controller before assigning the session logged in variable check, if its not then session_destroy & do a header redirect to the login.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are worried about ID 126 being blocked even if it gets assigned to a new user.

Shouldn't be a problem, cause IDs in those cases (usally) get created in an auto increment fashion and the DB (MySQL for sure, most others probably, too) chooses the next higher value to the highest ever generated value in such an auto-increment field.

So if the highes assigned value was 1234, then you can delete what you want, the next value is going to be 1235.

So your problem is not really a problem as it seems to me.

Comment: But when the user have the session id 126, the server side will think that is a valid user id, because I check the user id in the session at server side. So, it many have some unpredictable or strange error.

Comment: the session id would be 126 ... that would be pretty predictable and hence make your authentication mechanism pretty vulnerable.

Comment: that's mean, when the user make a request, I need query the db again to check have the user id or not? It really cost a lot if there are many users.

Comment: ? ... security is no 1 requirement! generate a random string then as an ID, but not a sequential number.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that I can think of this,

1.) Store the user credentials in the db,
every time the user makes an action you can check for credentials then kick the user out if already banned. I don't think its

2.) cache the logged in users, the cache should be global so the banned user's session can be checked